# FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED=1 flag not working when initialising Flipper in iOS app (iOS NO APPLICATION SELECTED)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, flipper

I followed all the steps from:

https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native-ios/

(both automatic and manual installation).

**`FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED=1` doesn't seem to work**.

**Flipper connects to device but it is not initialised in the app** and `NO APPLICATION SELECTED` error shows up.

[image]

**Flag looks to be set OK**:

[image]

```
RN: 0.66.4
Flipper: 0.144.0
```

Podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'


target 'MYAPP' do
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => true
  )

  pod 'SwiftLint'
  
  target 'MYAPPTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  
  # Enables Flipper.
 
  use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.144.0' }, configurations: ['debug'])
end

post_install do |installer|
  flipper_post_install(installer)

  react_native_post_install(installer)
  __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
    end
  end
end
```

AppDelegate:

```
#if DEBUG
// #if FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED. <-- this has to be commented for Flipper to start
// otherwise Flipper is never imported and initialised, same for 
import FlipperKit
// #endif
#endif

@UIApplicationMain

  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, RCTBridgeDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate,
  UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, RNAppAuthAuthorizationFlowManager {

  private func initializeFlipper(with application: UIApplication) {
    #if DEBUG
    //#if FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED // If this is not commented Flipper never starts.
    let client = FlipperClient.shared()
    let layoutDescriptorMapper = SKDescriptorMapper(defaults: ())

    // Notes: FlipperKitLayoutComponentKitSupport.setUpWith and 
    // client?.add(FlipperReactPerformancePlugin.sharedInstance()) need to be 
    // commented below for the build to work
    // FlipperKitLayoutComponentKitSupport.setUpWith(layoutDescriptorMapper)
    client?.add(FlipperKitLayoutPlugin(rootNode: application, with: layoutDescriptorMapper!))
    client?.add(FKUserDefaultsPlugin(suiteName: nil))
    client?.add(FlipperKitReactPlugin())
    client?.add(FlipperKitNetworkPlugin(networkAdapter: SKIOSNetworkAdapter()))
    // client?.add(FlipperReactPerformancePlugin.sharedInstance())
    client?.start()
    // #endif
    #endif
  }
```

Related questions:

https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/948

**Note:** I couldn't find anything about adding flag `FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED` to `SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS` (in Build settings for debug build) in Flipper docs.

Comment: Having the same issue and while digging deeper I found  that either DEBUG or FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED are false while evaluating. My issue on github is here, with some steps that might help you: https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/213